# Multiplying a varchar and a decimal field together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that contains the field as:

`doses_given decimal(9,2)`

that I want to multiply against this field:

`drug_units_per_dose varchar(255)`

So I did something like this:

```
CAST(ppr.drug_units_per_dose as decimal(9,2)) * doses_given dosesGiven,
```

However, looking at the data, I notice some odd characters:

```
select distinct(drug_units_per_dose) from patient_prescr

NULL

1
1-2
1-4
1.5
1/2
1/4
10
12
15
1Â½
2
2-3
2.5
20
2Â½
3
3-4
30
4
5
6
7
8
Â½
```

As you can see, I am getting some characters that cannot be `CAST` to decimal. On the web page these fields are interpreted as a small `1/2` symbol:

[image]

Is there anyway to replace the `Â½` field with a .5 to accurately complete the multiplication?

Comment: What does 1-2 mean?.what do u want it to be?

Comment: 1-2 probably means "one to two" which is not a number so no math can be done.  As far as the strange one goes, step 1 is to do something from preventing more values like that from being entered.  Step 2 is to update the existing records.

Comment: You can't convert a non-numeric character to a number. The only clean solution is to add another numeric field and store units per dose there as a number. You aren't duplicating information because `drug_units_per_dose` is essentially a label, not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a rather nasty problem.  You have a field `drug_units_per_dose` that a normal human being would consider to be an integer or floating point number.  Clearly, the designers of your database are super-normal people, and they understand a much wider range of options for this concept.

I say that partly tongue in cheek, but to make an important point.  The column in the database does not represent a number, at least not in all cases.  I would suggest that you have a translation table for `drug_units_per_dose`.  It would have columns such as:

```
1       1
1/2     0.5
3-4     ??
```

I realize that you will have hundreds of rows, and a lot of them will look redundant because they will be "50,50" and "100,100".  However, if you want to keep control of the business logic for turning these strings into a number, then a lookup table seems like the sanest approach.

Comment: I think the OP should declare which medical organization he works for, so I can avoid their prescriptions.

Comment: If you are posting on SO, you do not have to worry about avoiding our prescriptions :)

Answer (score 2):

The 1/2 symbol is ascii character 189, so to replace:

```
CAST(REPLACE(ppr.drug_units_per_dose,char(189),'.5') as decimal(9,2)) * doses_given dosesGiven
```

Answer (score 0):

CAST(prod.em_amccom_comset AS int) * invline.qtyinvoiced AS setcredits

syntax - CAST(char_value as int) * integer_value as alias_name

Comment: Could you add text to explain your answer?